# Why do I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT in OpenGL ES for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, exc-bad-access, vertex-buffer

What I need to do is draw a vertex array that has more than 256 elements. When I have less than that many, and I use GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE in my call to glDrawElements, everything works fine. When I have more than 256 elements, it starts drawing back at the first vertex again (i.e., last element [256 - 255, whatever] connects with first [1, or 0], and further elements don't get drawn). If I use GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT instead, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What gives?

```
int indexLim = self.animIndex;

GLushort glIndLim = (GLushort)indexLim;

Vertex localVertices[glIndLim];
GLubyte localIndices[glIndLim];

for(GLushort i=0; i < glIndLim; i++)
{
    x = (float)i;
    y = [[data objectAtIndex:i ] floatValue];

    x = x*xScale + xOffset;
    y = y*yScale + yOffset;

    localVertices[i].Position[0] = x;
    localVertices[i].Position[1] = y;
    localVertices[i].Position[2] = z;
    localVertices[i].Color[0]    = r;
    localVertices[i].Color[1]    = g;
    localVertices[i].Color[2]    = b;
    localVertices[i].Color[3]    = a;
    localIndices[i] = i;
}    

// setupVBOs
GLuint vertexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(localVertices), localVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint indexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(localIndices), localIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(_colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));


//glDrawElements(GL_LINE_STRIP, glIndLim, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0); // Works, but only draws 256 elements
glDrawElements(GL_LINE_STRIP, glIndLim, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS!!!!
```

Comment: Just to clarify, when I say the first one "only draws 256 elements", what I think is really happening is that it is starting over and going back through the vertex array again, and keeps drawing from there until the "glIndLim" is met. But it won't move into the 257th element, only loops through the first 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried defining:

```
GLubyte localIndices[glIndLim];
```

as

```
GLushort localIndices[glIndLim];
```

?

The reasoning is that if that should represent the index for your vertex, it should admit all possible values for GLushort, otherwise the local index will always be a GLubyte.

Comment: Thanks sergio, I am an idiot. That was totally the problem. I have been staring at this code for too long.

Comment: You are welcome, Adam. 4 eyes always see better than 2... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Log your index value each time through the loop. It sounds like you're incrementing a variable beyond its maximum value and it is becoming a negative number.